# SQL- do not select those rows which contain specific text

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, relational-database

I cannot use Except keywords due to version problem. Anyone here know. How can i select all rows except not those rows which contain specific text.select all rows except those which contain specific text.I cannot use Except Keyword due to version problem in MS S.Q.L

Comment: What are you using to fetch data from database? EF ? You can use linq `Where` statement

Comment: What have you even tried.

Comment: i have tried except keyword but it do not support to ms sql due to version problem

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from your_table
where some_column not like '%specific text%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from Table1 
where EmpPU NOT Like '%CSE%' 
AND EmpPU NOT Like '%ECE%' 
AND EmpPU NOT Like '%EEE%'
```